# How to make this background image with CSS3

Tags: css, background

I would like to ask you if you know how to make the attached image with CSS3. I have tried few webs to make gradients but I didn't get it. :(.

I will have the original imagen but I would like to make the background with CSS3 and not with an image.

Do you know if is possible? How can i make it?

[image]

Comment: CSS3 is not a solution for world peace. Everything does *not need* to be done via CSS. Images have their own place and especially in use-cases like this, it's worthwhile to not spend time and effort on writing convoluted CSS which provides no real gain. What's your problem with a simple background image?

Comment: Thanks, abhitalks. I know that I can use "backround-image" but if it's posible use CSS3.. why not? :D . Also the page will load more faster for sure if it's with CSS3..  Anyway, Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
CSS multiple background is great solution. You can play with it here - http://elrumordelaluz.github.io/draGGradients

Comment: This should go in comment.

Comment: Thank you, DonSinDRom. I will play with that!! Thank you¡!